# "status": 404, "error": "Not Found", "path": "/GetProduct"

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

My controller class is -

```
package com.javatechie.crud.example.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import com.javatechie.crud.example.entity.Product;
import com.javatechie.crud.example.service.ProductService;

public class ProductListController {

    @Autowired
    private ProductService service; 
    @GetMapping("/GetProduct")
    public List<Product> addProducts(@RequestBody Product products) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {      
            System.out.println("Inside addProducts controller method");
        return service.saveProducts(1);
    }   
}
```

My entity class is -

```
package com.javatechie.crud.example.entity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="PRODUCT_TBL")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String quantity;
    private double price;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }
    public void setQuantity(String quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }   
}
```

JpaRepository implementation is -

```
package com.javatechie.crud.example.entity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="PRODUCT_TBL")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String quantity;
    private double price;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }
    public void setQuantity(String quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }   
}
```

And the service class is -

```
package com.javatechie.crud.example.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.javatechie.crud.example.entity.Product;
import com.javatechie.crud.example.repository.ProductRepository;

@Service
public class ProductService {

    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository repository;
    
    public List<Product> saveProducts(int id) {
        return repository.GetRepo(id);
    }   
}
```

And , the unexpected output which it is giving is -

[image]

Database table is as follows -

[image]

The output which I was expecting is the json body with sql record having id , name ,price,quantity . How can I achieve this output with native query only ? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add @RestController and @RequestMapping annotations for processing incoming REST requests.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class ProductListController {

    @Autowired
    private ProductService service; 
    @GetMapping("/GetProduct")
    public List<Product> addProducts(@RequestBody Product products) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {      
        System.out.println("Inside addProducts controller method");
        return service.saveProducts(1);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Yes , it worked out . After adding these annotations .It gave expected output .Thank you very much for responding .